# C# - Problem Executing Application Outside Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I'm with a problem executing an implementation in application. I have some webservices that I can work, run, and access its informations normally in Visual Studio.

The connection with the webservices addresses can be access via IE, for example, and the services are alright.

I execute the executable file in application, and when it is tried to access the webservices, I get the 403 (Forbidden) error.

The credentials are fine because the line that triggers the error is when an method of the webservice is used after the authentication is done.

Even running in administrator privileges in application it shows the same error. And the WCF service is running by a local administrator user.

I've already tried to request in the same scope that the method is being used, but unsuccessful.

```
private SI_Out_SyncClient WebserviceConnection ()
{

    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);

    binding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;

    binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 5, 0);
    binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 5, 0);
    binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 5, 0);

    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
    binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;

    EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(Library.Environment.GetGlobalString("ENDPOINT"));

    var client = new SI_Out_SyncClient(binding, address);

    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Library.Environment.GetGlobalString("USER");
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Library.Environment.GetGlobalString("PASSWORD");

    return client;
}
```

I expect to run in application as I can run in debug, but in the correct way, without setting debug compilation mode to true.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to access the sevice in fiddler and see how the authentication is getting resolved. If it is doing NTLM or kerberos you may have to do the same in the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was going on.

In my case, the administrator user that is running the WCF service hadn't access to internet.

A silly mistake, but it is worth to register since I didn't find an orientation like this in my researches.